# Find the sum of the multiples of 7 or 3 under 763

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble finding the correct answer for this homework.
Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/InclusionExclusion.shtml

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. You need to show more of your own attempts at the problem than just "I'm having trouble." Exactly where is your difficulty? Also, the problem statement is not clear. Are you to add all numbers that are divisible by 7 or by 3 or by both, or is this two problems, first relating to divisibility by 7 and the second to divisibility by 3?

Answer (score 1):

The multiples of $3$ are $3,6,9,\dots 762$. Their sum is

$$3+6+\cdots + 763 = 3\cdot(1+2+\cdots + 254)$$

You should already know what $1+2+\cdots n$ is.

---

Now do the same with multiples of $7$.

---

Once you are done, ask yourself:

1. Did you count any number twice?
2. If yes, which ones did you count twice?

Comment: This is a good answer, however the way I understood the question was the sum of multiples of $7$ under $763$ on one side, and the sum of multiples of $3$ on the other side. You're interpretation might be the good one though.